# receiving error calling a function from my body. <function your_box at 0x031E0C88>

Tags: python-3.x

receiving error
calling a function from my body.

```
def your_box(num_items):
    item = ['Common Item!', 'Rare Item!', 'Epic Item!', 'Legendary Item!']
    print('Opening your Box:')
    for num in range(1, 4):
        print('Item '+str(num)+' of 4 ----', random.choice(item))
        break
```

and in the body of the loop i have placed the below, so when the user inputs 3. The boxes should come up on dsplay.

```
elif users_choice == '3':
        if boxes<=0:
            print('Insufficient Boxes')
            break
        if boxes>=0:
            boxes-=1
            boxes_opened+=1
            print (open_box)
            break
```

i was also considering using if statement for the probability of the 4 items being choosen, but i couldnt seem to make it work in the body of the function.

```
def your_box(num_items):
    print('Opening Box:')
    rarity = random.randint(1,100)
    for num_items in range(100):
        if rarity <= 5:
            return ('Legendary')
        elif rarity <= 15:
            return ('Epic')
        elif rarity <= 50:
            return('Rare')
        elif rarity<=100:
            return('Common')
        break
```

Comment: What specifically is the error? What is the full traceback? Try to elaborate a bit more.

Comment: instead of displaying the function. the program displays (<function your_box at 0x031E0C88>)

Comment: To run a function, you need to call it, using 2 brackets, like this: `open_box()`

Comment: now im receiving (TypeError: your_box() missing 1 required positional argument: 'num_items)

Comment: You need to include an argument for your function, like this `your_box(num_items)`, except replace `num_items` with the number of items you want to choose from.